# How can I get a list of strings from the form and return some option results to a dropdown list using AJAX?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to get the municipality codes from the hidden inputs that are linked to the selected checkbox.  How can I get the value from these hidden inputs and create a string array and send those values to the TAGetDistrictsByMunicipality controller method?  The TAGetDistrictsByMunicipality method returns a string array that needs to get added to the `SelectedDistricts` select list after a municipality is selected or unselected.

I've tried `$(this).parent().text().trim()`, but that gets the text of the label, not the value of the code input.  Is there a way using JQuery to get the code value for each selected municipality in a div, instead of trying to add each item individually as they are selected? I need to add or remove values from the array based on if the checkbox is selected or not.

**View - HTML**

```
<div class="form-table form-table-inner" id="muniTable">
<div>
    <label for="Municipalities_0__Selected">
        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="Municipalities_0__Selected" name="Municipalities[0].Selected" value="true">002 - TOWN OF TEST
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Text field is required." id="Municipalities_0__Text" name="Municipalities[0].Text" value="002 - TOWN OF TEST">
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Code field is required." id="Municipalities_0__Code" name="Municipalities[0].Code" value="002">
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Municipalities_0__ID" name="Municipalities[0].ID" value="1">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-2" style="padding-top: 6px;">
        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LimitToDistrict field is required." id="LimitToDistrict" name="LimitToDistrict" value="true">
        <label><b>Limit to district</b></label>
    </span>
    <select disabled="" class="form-control col-3 d-inline-block input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedDistrict field is required." id="SelectedDistrict" name="SelectedDistrict">
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

**View - Javascript**

```
var munis = new Array();
$("#muniTable :checkbox").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { muniSelections: munis },
        url: '@Url.Action("TAGetDistrictsByMunicipality", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString())',
        success: function (data) {
            //Display districts to dropdown list
            for (var x; x < data.length(); x++) {
                var item = $('<option></option>').attr({ value: data[x].text(), text = data[x].text() }).text();
                $('#SelectedDistrict').append( item ); //Add option to select list
            }

        }
    });
    }
    else { 
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { muniSelections: munis },
        url: '@Url.Action("TAGetDistrictsByMunicipality", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString())',
        success: function (data) {
            //Display districts to dropdown list, add options to the select list
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length(); x++) {
                var item = $('<option></option>').attr({ value: data[x].text(), text = data[x].text() }).text();
                $('#SelectedDistrict').append( item ); //Add option to select list
            }
        }
    });
    }
});
```

**Controller - Returns a list of strings**

```
public JsonResult TAGetDistrictsByMunicipality(List<string> muniSelections)
{
    SortingSpecification sortingSpec = new SortingSpecification();
    ReportDataSortHelper.AddSortByDistrictStateCode(ref sortingSpec);
    MunicipalityDistrictMapManager.GetMunicipalityDistrictMapsWithMatchingFields(
        null,
        out EntityCollection<MunicipalityDistrictMapEntity> districtEntities,
        sortingSpec,
        fillDistrictEntities : true
    );

    EntityCollection<DistrictEntity> districts = new EntityCollection<DistrictEntity>();
    var MunicipalityEntities = new List<MunicipalityEntity>();

    foreach (var muniCode in muniSelections) {
        MunicipalityManager.GetMunicipalityByMunicipalityCode(muniCode, out MunicipalityEntity muni);
        MunicipalityEntities.Add(muni);
    }

    foreach (MunicipalityEntity municipality in MunicipalityEntities) {
        MunicipalityEntity mun = (MunicipalityEntity)municipality;
        List<int> matches = districtEntities.FindMatches(MunicipalityDistrictMapFields.MunicipalityId == municipality.MunicipalityId);
        foreach (int m in matches) {
            if (municipality.MunicipalityDistrictMap[m].District.Type == DistrictEntity.Type_School 
                || municipality.MunicipalityDistrictMap[m].District.Type == DistrictEntity.Type_Special){
                List<int> dmatch = districts.FindMatches(DistrictFields.DistrictId == municipality.MunicipalityDistrictMap[m].DistrictId);
                if (dmatch.Count == 0) {
                    districts.Add(districtEntities[m].District);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IOrderedEnumerable<DistrictEntity> sorted = districts.OrderBy(d => d.DistrictStateCodeString);
    EntityCollection<DistrictEntity> sortedDistricts = new EntityCollection<DistrictEntity>();
    sortedDistricts.AddRange(sorted);

    List<string> districtCodeStrings = new List<string>();
    foreach (var sortedDistrict in sortedDistricts) {
        districtCodeStrings.Add(sortedDistrict.DistrictStateCodeDescriptionString);
    }

    return Json(new
    {
        districts = districtCodeStrings
    });
}
```

Comment: Let's work on this step by step, 1st is you want to get the hidden input fields' value correct?

Comment: Yes, I need the hidden input's value. I need to add that value to an array of strings and pass that to the controller.  The controller will return another array of strings, which need to be put as options into the select list.